# Is it possible to load and encode images to base64 fast in C#?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, base64

I want to load an image and directly encode this to a base64 string. Small/low-res pictures load fast but loading a picture taken by an iPhone 5 for example (2448 x 3264, 2.61 MB) takes ages. Is there a way to load these images faster in my application?

Here is my C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        //Setup OpenFileDialog

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    string sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    textBox1.Text = sFileName;
                    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = sFileName;
                    using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(sFileName))
                    {
                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bm.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                            textBox3.Text = base64;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Image.FromFile() could help you a lot

Comment: Lots of unnecessary expensive code.  No real point using the Bitmap class when you can use the file as-is.  No point in giving the TextBox class a heart attack with a 5.2 megabyte string.  No point in using MemoryStream.ToArray() when you can use MemoryStream.GetBuffer().

Comment: What do you want to archieve with the image as base64?

Comment: @Campl3r Finally encrypt the base64 with AES

Comment: Okay. Something's been lost in translation here. There is **no** sane reason to base64 encode anything and *then* encrypt it with AES. The other way around (Encrypt then base 64), yes. But this way, no. Not at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think you can: This is the scheme: Image --> base64 string --> AES encrypted base64 string and how the **** can you encrypt a image?

Comment: In general, encryption transforms an *arbitrary* set of bytes into another *arbitrary* set of bytes. Their specific values or meanings are irrelevant. So, in this situation, the input could *easily* by the array returned by `ms.ToArray()`. All you do by base-64 encoding that array of bytes first is to bloat up the amount of data that needs to be encrypted by a third - and what you get as output is still going to be an arbitrary set of bytes - so if you need the *output* of the encryption to be handlable as e.g. text you have to perform a *second* round of encoding using e.g. base 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the method you are using is probably the most popular I've seen out there. I needed to convert images too so I wrote something using that same method. **However**, it was simply too inefficient and slow for me. I decided to look for workarounds. I found this small program written in C by [John Walker](http://www.fourmilab.ch) called [`base64.exe`](https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64). I made a wrapper around it with some modifications on the output.

The result is [Base64encoder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/base64encoder), but it was written relatively a long time ago. I've uploaded the source here: [Base64encoder_v2.1-source.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/base64encoder/files/v2.1/Base64encoder_v2.1-source.zip/download) (released under MIT License)

I've later made a C library that can be found here: https://github.com/joedf/base64.c (released under MIT License)

You can either fork the wrapper or fork the c library into a c# library, or use some other library or write something from scratch... :/

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you do not convert big sized images into Base64..
If you try to base64 larger images you will end up with a great deal of code in your html and lose out on the performance benefits...

References [this](https://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525) & [this](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/base64-images.html).

Comment: I am not using HTML at all, it's a windows forms program